# Sinatra API params from URL

Tags: ruby, api, mongodb, sinatra

I built a basic Sinatra/Mongodb backed API, and am trying to figure out how to filter results based on params passed into through the URL.

My Product class:

```
class Product
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :p_id, type: Integer
  field :_id, type: Integer, default: -> { p_id }
  field :title, type: String
  field :price, type: BigDecimal
  field :url, type: String
  field :upc, type: Integer
  field :bundle, type: Boolean
  field :var, type: Boolean
end
```

My current route displaying all products:

```
#localhost:9292/products
get '/products' do
  @products = Product.all
  rabl :products
end
```

How can I filter what products are displayed based on what params the user sends. For example, if the url requested is `localhost:9292/products/&bundle=1` I want to show only products where bundle is true, or if the requested url is `localhost:9292/products/&bundle=1&var=0` I want to display products where bundle is true and var is false.

Answer (score 1):

Just use chaining:

```
@products = Product.all
@products = @products.where(bundle: true) if params[:bundle] == '1'
@products = @products.where(var: false) if params[:var] == '0'
```